# What places did Terry Brooks forget Walker Boh was missing his lower right arm?

Tags: books, continuity, character-development, shannara

Since I was a child, soon after Terry Brooks published *The Sword of Shannara* (1977), I have enjoyed his writing. I know he has his critics, and as any author (especially of sci-fi/fantasy), he has struggled with continuity issues.

I noticed a drastic one in reading the *Heritage of Shannara* series. One that I discovered [Brooks admitted was a challenge and issue in this set](https://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2012/07/interview-with-terry-brooks-part-2/) (from an interview with Patrick Rothfuss, Brooks' words):

> My biggest, most horrible consistency issue was with Walker Boh in the Heritage of Shannara set.  Early on, Walker lost his arm up to the elbow.  Even now, I forget which one.  Back then, I had to deal with him for those four books and then later in the Voyage of the Jerle Shannara set for two more.  What happened was I kept forgetting which arm he’d lost.  Or I would have him use the missing arm or his hands (plural).  So I had to keep going back and checking everything he did that involved the use of his arms.  Even with at least six or eight readings of the books, I missed one or two.  But the kid in Boise didn’t.  So I heard all about it.  Even worse, the publisher reversed the print of the cover art that featured Walker with his arm missing and showed the wrong arm gone.
>
> There were other incidents of this sort, but that was the worst.

From *The Druid of Shannara*, it is clear that it is Walker's right arm, to the elbow, that gets removed (p.7, 109, et al.). I seem to recall three places that I noticed an inconsistency while I was rereading the series, but at present can only track down two (I think there is another in *The Druid of Shannara*, but it may be in one of the two following books in the series):

- "Walker folded his **hands** before him thoughtfully." (p.301, *The Druid of Shannara*)
- "Walker took them to it's [Southwatch's] walls, to where the obsidian surface rose smooth and black out of the earth, and he placed his **hands** against the stone." (p.402, *The Talismans of Shannara*)

The question is, are there any other places where Brooks wrote Walker's character, forgetting he was missing his right arm? They would be in:

- The latter part of the *Heritage of Shannara* series

  - *The Druid of Shannara*
  - *The Elf Queen of Shannara*
  - *The Talismans of Shannara*
- The historically later Walker Boh in *The Voyage of the Jerle Shannara* series

  - *Ilse Witch*
  - *Antrax*
  - *Morgawr*

Clear use of the wrong hand/arm, reference to hands (plural), or some other action that really would require two arms/hands to do might qualify. I'm only interested in the writing within the books (as Brooks notes, some art might have been flipped that would be a publishing issue, but not necessarily a continuity issue Brooks introduced).

My interest in this is that I have a book series I may someday publish, and learning from the mistakes of others may help me to not make similar mistakes in the future. Seeing how many places Brooks missed, d*espite knowing he was struggling with this detail*, helps to understand how small details, yet *major* to the story/writing, can make or break the reader's experience.

So I'm interested if anyone has cataloged all the places this discrepancy about Walker creeps into the above works.

(NOTE: I chose to post on this SE site, rather than like [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) SE, because I'm *sure* I'm more likely to find *readers* of Brooks' work here).

Comment: It's a good question, I've read the books several times but never noticed this. As for how to avoid such mistakes, I think most fantasy authors let a lot of trusted people with in-depth knowledge of the setting proof-read the drafts.